# How BFS algorithm tells us the shortest path from source to target?

Tags: algorithm

I know what is BFS algorithm and how it is implemented but will anyone tell me how it is used to find the shortest path between two points... I am asking specially for pacman game board. How do the ghosts use BFS to reach the target (pacman)?

Comment: What makes you think the ghosts in PacMan use BFS?

Comment: We are told that we have to use BFS to search the shortest path to pacman

Comment: http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/tower-defense/ this can be useful for conceptualizing how it works

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the Pacman map into a graph of connected nodes. Convert each cell of the map into a node of the graph. Connect them if you can get from one cell to the other directly (ie. if they are ajacent).

If the ghost is in a corridor then he can go to two adjacent cells. So the current cell has two neighbor nodes in the graph. If he is at an intersection, then there are more paths to go. And so on for every cell.

The ghost then searches the graph as if it were a tree rooted at the cell the ghost is currently at.

[image]

- Note that if the BFS turns out to search left-to-right in this picture, then it might find many nodes down to '15', but it will then find '2' and have the shortest path.
- It does not matter if the '14' then turns out to have another connection and get to '2' via '1' because that path **has** to be longer than the path we already found (because the path to '14' is longer already).

You have to somehow remember which path you took in the current tree ('current' because for the next ghost-position it will be different). In DFS you would use the stack you have anyway. Here we use BFS so what you could do is let each node in the graph have an empty extra field. When you do the BFS you store the node's predecessor in that field. Example: in 5's extra field you store '6'. When you found the goal '2' you walk through that chain: 2->3->4->5->6, then you reverse it!

Comment: Ok, then how to move the ghosts in their paths using BFS?

Comment: For example if the ghost is in a corridor and Pacman is right next to it: Then the ghost starts at the current node as if it is the root of a tree. The root has two children in this case. One of the two children is occupied by Pacman. The ghost has found Pacman.

Comment: @AzharSindhi You can keep track of the nodes you've searched and use them to backtrack from where you found Pacman

Comment: @AzharSindhi Any more questions? Did you understand my answer and comment? I am happy to help!

Comment: @BerndElkemann Thank you very much... Do we have to use BFS in every step of ghosts or just at the intersection points?

Comment: @AzharSindhi I would do it at every step because that produces more accurate results: e.g. a ghost then can decide to turn around if it realizes that pacman changed position.

Comment: @AzharSindhi I added information about backtracking to my answer. Please tell me if this helps you.

Comment: @BerndElkemann Thank you very much I have nearly completed my game through your help. One request to you is please elaborate about backtracking to get the actual path to pacman? It would be better if you take the nodes at intersecting points for giving example

Comment: @AzharSindhi I added a nice paragraph about backtracking at the end of my answer. It uses all cells (not just intersections) because (1) it is easier to implement and (2) produces much better results.

Answer (score 2):

**BFS**, in contrast to what another answer mentions, **does correctly find the shortest path between nodes in unweighted graphs**. In an unweighted graph, the length of a path is simply the number of edges from the source to the destination.

The pacman board can be thought of as an unweighted graph: Each square of the board (that is not a wall) is a node, and has edges to its direct neighbors.

When a ghost searches for the shortest path to PacMan, it starts a BFS search on this graph from the square it sits on. Once the search finds PacMan, we can backtrack our way back to find the shortest path. We will obtain a series of moves (e.g. North -> West -> South ...), and the ghost will need to follow this path to get to the current location of pacman.

However, if pacman is also moving at the same time as the ghost, we need to re-run BFS after every move to find the shortest path to the new position.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer? How will we obtain a series of moves (North-> West -> South...) by backtracking our way?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. BFS is just a manner of searching a graph or a tree.

To calculate the shortest path between two points you need an algorithm doing just that. Dijkstras algoritm is simple to implement with a priority queue. One could argue that Dijkstras algorithm is a special case of BFS (priority queue vs. queue).

> We are told that we have to use BFS to search the shortest path to pacman

Using a lot more than four minutes with GIMP I managed to create a picture as why BFS depth is not enough for determining the shortest path.

[image]

Red G is a ghost. The yellow P is our hero. The blue dots is the intersections with the decisions as to what path the ghost should take. The green line is the shortest path. The pink? line is the path first found by BFS.

EDIT: I just realized I made a bad choice for the paths, they are both three levels away. I just traced the dots not the actual branchings. I'm sure there are more appropriate placements for G and P that shows the BFS - shortest path discrepancy more clearly.

The title of the question might be a miscommunication. BFS is a reasonable way for a ghost to find Pac-Man, it is not the shortest path though.

EDIT: In response to comments. This answers the question if the Pac-Man board is represented as a weighted graph. Something like

```
|-----A-----|X|------B-----|
|XXXXX|XXXXX|X|XXXXXX|XXXXX|
oXXXXX3XXXXX|X|XXXXXX|XXXXXo
|XXXXX|XXXXX|X|XXXXXX|XXXXX|
C-----D-----E-F------G-----H
```

Or as a neighbour representation

```
AD 4
CD 6 etc..
```

If stuff is all pixels BFS reduces to *try most paths* in an extremely unsophisticated fashion.

I stole the pacman background from http://trelford.com/blog/image.axd?picture=maze_thumb.png via google.

As for the actual implementation of the ghosts movements an in depth analysis is available at http://gameinternals.com/post/2072558330/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Comment: BFS and Dijkstra are fine. A-star makes no sense in a maze with tight corridors. But this is what many many people get wrong so you are in good company ;-)

Comment: @BerndElkemann Indeed for a pacman grid A* is useless.

Comment: Ah i see your answer was not targeted at Pacman but more general. Yes good point: for other games A-star is often the best thing we can do.

Comment: What on earth does the width of the corridors have to do with, well, anything?  The reason A* doesn't help is that weights/distances are uniform, so that the first "solution" node found by BFS must also be one with the shortest path.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe then where we use BFS algorithm? please explain

Comment: @AzharSindhi if the ghosts use BFS they are not finding the shortest path, they are just employing a simple method to find a reasonable way to our hero.

Comment: -1 Unless I'm missing something, this answer is simply incorrect. In unweighted graphs, BFS can be used to produce a shortest path. BFS is not looking for a shortest path but you can easily modify an algorithm for BFS to show one. Can you explain how you got different paths for BFS vs. Dijsktra?

Comment: @Patrick87 It is not an unweighted graph. The reasonable weight/length  interpretation is in my opinion the number of dots/wakas to get to Pac-Man. The depth of the search tree is the number of crossings the ghosts gets to decide where to go. This is the blue dots in my picture.

Comment: I'm still not understanding something. Are you taking the "weight" of a path to be number of "decisions" that are made? I think the most natural "weight" of a path is simply the number of dots. Or perhaps you're imagining a graph whose vertices are the intersections? My graph is the one whose vertices are the dots. I believe my interpretation is superior in all practical respects since the speed is constant w.r.t. dots but not w.r.t. intersections.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe But how are "crossings" a useful way to find the shortest path? Some vertices are farther away than others, but the ghost moves at a constant speed w.r.t. dots and a variable speed w.r.t. "crossings".